# Storyboard and xib use in same project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, storyboard, xib

I am stumbling over what I believe is probably a fundamental misunderstanding of how classes work in Objective-C. I am using Storyboards but in this app I wanted to create a simple custom date picker view for a textfield on one of my view controllers.  However, I seem to be having a problem accessing any of the properties of the date picker class from my view controller:

First I modeled my CustomDatePicker.xib in IB as follows:

[image]

I have created a custom class by sublcassing UIView as follows:

CustomPicker.h

```
@interface CustomPickerView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker* datePicker;

@end
```

CustomerPicker.m

```
@implementation CustomPickerView

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 258)];
    if (self) {
        [self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomPickerView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In my ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.customPickerView=[[CustomPickerView alloc] init];

    // THE MAIN ISSUE IS...
    // Following line has no effect on how picker is presented ???
    self.customPickerView.datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeTime;

    self.dateField.inputView=self.customPickerView;
}
```

When the textfield is tapped, my CustomDatePicker pops up fine. However, I can't seem to set the .datePickerMode either from the viewDidLoad method of my ViewController. The only way I can change the .datePickerMode is through IB and of course that's not going to work at run-time.

I have wired up the outlet in IB and am able to access the datePicker.date from within the class but not the ViewController.

I have researched and viewed a number of ways to implement this concept. My question isn't how to implement a CustomDatePicker it is "Why can't I access properties of my CustomDatePicker from the ViewController that instantiated it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see solution here at:

[Objective-C Custom Class Actions and Outlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520695/objective-c-custom-class-actions-and-outlets)

Answer (score 1):

I successfully changed the datePickerMode property when I loaded the NIB like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomPickerView" owner:self options:nil];
    self.customPickerView = (CustomPickerView *)[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
    self.customPickerView.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;

    self.dateField.inputView = self.customPickerView;
}
```

And you can probably remove your custom view's `init` method altogether. I've never seen a NIB loaded in the `init` method like you're doing. While it might be possible, I believe that's what is causing your problem. Loading the NIB in `viewDidLoad` of the ViewController and setting it directly seems more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I see what you've done but I really want to keep the nib loading within the CustomPickerClass that I've written. That way when I instantiate the CustomPickerClass, the nib is loaded. Also, implementing as you've described causes other issues in regards to methods local to the CustomPicker Class like when the Done button is pressed. I left this part of the code out to focus on my main question.